# Postman GUI not visible in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

For some reason in Ubuntu 17.10 when I install postman via these instructions, the GUI window for postman is invisible and I can't use it.

https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/?utm_source=hootsuite&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=

I've noticed that this also happens when installing Android Studio, however once I've gotten through the initial setup wizard it works fine. To do that I had to alt + ~ to show the preview window and then press the appropriate keys to get through the wizard. On Postman I can't do anything.

Anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it? Postman opens and again I can see the tile image if I press alt + ~ but the actual window won't display.

Happy to provide more information but I'm not sure what. Let me know if you need something in order to help you answer it. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are using Wayland instead of Xorg, since it is default for 17.10.  Many programs don't integrate well with Wayland yet. File a bug report. In the meantime, see if it works well with an Xorg session.

Comment: @ravery I didn't even think of that - good suggestion. However to my surprise it turns out I'm using Xorg and Wayland isn't even an option. The menu to select Wayland isn't even there. Running this shows X11 "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution. I use HDMI output on my monitor but for some reason it doesn't show anything when I reboot, so I have to plug in the VGA cable as well (and then later it will detect the HDMI). I didn't notice it before but it seems that when I do that it thinks I have two monitors plugged in when in fact it's the same monitor.

If I unplug the VGA it works. Maybe I'll just use the VGA only from now on.

Comment: do you have a dual graphics intel/nVidia?  and no wayland? are you using KDE/Kubuntu?

Comment: My graphics from the about screen is "Intel® HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)" and using standard Ubuntu 17.10.